# JPA: Join and order by/limit constraint on child table of OneToMany relation with fluent or @Query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Given the following model:

```kotlin
@Entity
open class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    open val id: Long? = null

    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @OrderColumn(name = "version")
    private var children: MutableList<Child> = mutableListOf()

    fun addChild(child: Child) {
        child.parent = this
        children.add(child)
    }

    fun getChildPosition(child: Child): Int {
        return children.indexOf(child)
    }
}

@Entity
open class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    open val id: Long? = null

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    open var parent: Parent? = null

    @Column(nullable = false)
    open var data: String? = null

    @Column(name = "version")
    open var version: Int? = null

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    private fun prepareVersion() {
        if (parent != null) {
            version = parent?.getChildPosition(this)
        }
    }
}

interface MyProjection {
  // parent.id, child.id, child.version, child.data 
}

@Repository
interface ParentRepository : JpaRepository<Parent, UUID> {
  @Query("?")
  fun findWithLatestChild(id: Long?): MyProjection?
}
```

Is it possible to use either the JPA method naming convention or a JPQL query to do the following:

- join parent and child on the parent.id.
- order the children on the version (desc) and limit the result to 1.
- project the properties/columns as noted in the mock projection interface above.

*Update*:
If this isn't feasible, the following native query describes my intentions:

```sql
select p.id,c.* from parent p join child c on p.id = c.parent_id
where p.id = :parentId
order by c.version desc
limit 1
```

Comment: You SQL query would return only one record (limit 1) is that what you want to do?

Comment: It's exactly what I want to achieve; I want the latest version of the child in combination with the parent record.

Now, I just been made aware of Hibernate Envers, so the whole scenario might be solved in another way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can create a query like this:

```
@Query("select new packagename.MyProjection(c.parent.id, c.id, c.version, c.data ) " +
       "from Child where c.parent.id = :parentId order by c.version desc")
fun findWithLatestChild(id: Long?, pageable: Pageable): MyProjection?
```

And then call it with a PageRequest to limit the result to 1

```
findWithLatestChild(PageRequest.of(0,1));
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.